# Angular/HTML5 Change Page State, Keep focus on input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-history

I am currently developing a simple online English-Chinese dictionary using AngularJS. So when you type an English word (query) in a search field, relevant Chinese equivalents should come up.

For any query: I would like to have a unique address looking like this:

> `http://www.ezecdic.com/#/dictionary/{query}`

Here is what I want to implement:

So as I type a query in the search field, the URL of the browser address bar should be lively changing according to the query. I am using angular-ui-router for routing and here below I have included the code that I am using but not working.

Here is the routing code for the dictionary part:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dictionary', {
        url: '/dictionary/{query:.*}',
        templateUrl: '/static/templates/dictionary.html',
    }
)
```

Here is the controller for the dictionary:

```
angular.module('ezdic')
    .controller('DictionaryController', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.query = $stateParams.query;

        $scope.queryChanged = function () {
            $state.go('dictionary', {'query': $scope.query});
        };

        $scope.search = function (query, page, language) {
            // ... ...
        };

        $scope.search($scope.query);
    });
```

Here is the template code for the dictionary:

```
<div ng-controller="DictionaryController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="query" ng-change="queryChanged()" />
</div>
```

The problem is when I type in the search field, the URL changes but the search field loses the focus. This makes it impossible to keep typing. I also tried with `history.pushState()` or `location.hash` but they gave the same issue. I am not sure this is even possible. I just want the dictionary to behave the way I want. Any solutions are welcome!

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to type your whole search query and not lose focus if you set the **ng-model-options** to not fire ng-change until you leave the search box:

```
<div ng-controller="DictionaryController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="query" ng-change="queryChanged()" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
</div>
```